# Splitting a dataframe into separate CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a fairly large csv, looking like this:

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |   93644 |
|       2 |   63246 |
|       3 |   47790 |
|       3 |   39644 |
|       3 |   32585 |
|       1 |   19593 |
|       1 |   12707 |
|       2 |   53480 |
+---------+---------+
```

My intent is to

1. Add a new column
2. Insert a specific value into that column, 'NewColumnValue', on each row of the csv
3. Sort the file based on the value in Column1
4. Split the original CSV into new files based on the contents of 'Column1', removing the header

For example, I want to end up with multiple files that look like:

```
+---+-------+----------------+
| 1 | 19593 | NewColumnValue |
| 1 | 93644 | NewColumnValue |
| 1 | 12707 | NewColumnValue |
+---+-------+----------------+

+---+-------+-----------------+
| 2 | 63246 | NewColumnValue |
| 2 | 53480 | NewColumnValue |
+---+-------+-----------------+

+---+-------+-----------------+
| 3 | 47790 | NewColumnValue |
| 3 | 39644 | NewColumnValue |
| 3 | 32585 | NewColumnValue |
+---+-------+-----------------+
```

I have managed to do this using separate .py files:

Step1

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df.sort_values('Column1')
df['NewColumn'] = 'NewColumnValue'
df.to_csv('ready.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Step2

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
for key, rows in groupby(csv.reader(open("ready.csv")),
                         lambda row: row[0]):
    with open("%s.csv" % key, "w") as output:
        for row in rows:
            output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

But I'd really like to learn how to accomplish everything in a single .py file.  I tried this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#This processes a large CSV file.  
#It will dd a new column, populate the new column with a uniform piece of data for each row, sort the CSV, and remove headers
#Then it will split the single large CSV into multiple CSVs based on the value in column 0 
import pandas as pd
import csv
from itertools import groupby
df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df.sort_values('Column1')
df['NewColumn'] = 'NewColumnValue'
for key, rows in groupby(csv.reader((df)),
                         lambda row: row[0]):
    with open("%s.csv" % key, "w") as output:
        for row in rows:
            output.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```

but instead of working as intended, it's giving me multiple CSVs named after each column header.

Is that happening because I removed the header row when I used separate .py files and I'm not doing it here?  I'm not really certain what operation I need to do when splitting the files to remove the header.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just groupby `Column1` and save each group?

```
df = df.sort_values('Column1').assign(NewColumn='NewColumnValue')
print(df)

   Column1  Column2       NewColumn
0        1    93644  NewColumnValue
5        1    19593  NewColumnValue
6        1    12707  NewColumnValue
1        2    63246  NewColumnValue
7        2    53480  NewColumnValue
2        3    47790  NewColumnValue
3        3    39644  NewColumnValue
4        3    32585  NewColumnValue
```

---

```
for i, g in df.groupby('Column1'):
    g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), header=False, index_label=False)
```

Thanks to Unatiel for the [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124699/splitting-csv-based-on-content-of-one-column-after-having-done-some-other-manipu/46125692?noredirect=1#comment79214220_46125692). `header=False` will not write headers and `index_label=False` will not write an index column.

This creates 3 files:

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
```

Each having data corresponding to each `Column1` group.

Comment: Thanks.  And to answer your question, it was because when I spent today searching google for a solution to the problem pandas kept cropping up.  I didn't realize there was another way :)

Comment: I tried this method and it's producing some odd output files. Taking my file 13.csv as an example, it produces a file that has headers and additionally it seems to be inserting a headerless column with data I don't recognize.  e.g.  +------+---------+---------+----------------+
|      | Column1 | Column2 | NewColumn      |
| 6446 | 13      | 36457   | NewColumnValue |
+------+---------+---------+----------------+

Comment: You should try `g.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(i), header=False, index_label=False)`. `header=False` won't write the headers and `index_label=False` won't write that headerless column (this is the index of your dataframe).

Comment: Excellent!  I added a 'index=False' and it worked like a charm.  Thanks  cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ and @Unatiel

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to switch to `itertools` for the filtering, `pandas` has all of the necessary functionality built-in.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df.sort_values('Column1')  # Sorting isn't needed
df['NewColumn'] = 'NewColumnValue'
for key in df['Column1'].unique():  # For each value in Column1
    # These two steps can be combined into a single call
    # I'll separate for clarity:  
    # 1) filter the dataframe on the unique value
    dw = df[df['Column1']==key]   
    # 2) write the resulting dataframe without headers
    dw.to_csv("%s.csv" % key, header=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  It gave me an error on line 12, but after I changed it to  "dw.to_csv("%s.csv" % key, header=False) " it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.DataFrame` supports a method to write it's data as a csv [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You have no need for `csv` module in this case.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('source.csv')
df = df.sort_values('Column1').set_index('Column1')
df['NewColumn'] = 'NewColumnValue'
for key in df.index.unique():
    df.loc[key].to_csv('%d.csv' % int(key), header=False)
```

`for key df.index.unique():` will loop over every unique value in the index. In your example, it will loop over `(1, 2 , 3)`. `header=False` willmake sure the header isn't written to the output file.

And to explain why you get the wrong output in your example, try `print(list(df))`. This should output all the columns in df. This is why `for key, rows in csv.reader((df)):` iterates over the columns in df.

Actually, you should get 1 csv for every column in your dataframe, and their contents are likely something like `,[NAME_OF_COLUMN]` or maybe `,<itertools.... object at 0x.....>`.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  However, I'm getting a syntax error on: df = df.sort_values('Column1').set_index('Column1')

Comment: I don't get any syntax error on this, with python3. That being said, @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer is better, you should use it instead.

Comment: @SteveDallas Now that I think about it, `df = ` will indeed output a syntax error. I think you've added a new line by mistake after `df = `. I don't really see where the syntax error would be in my code. I'm a bit tired right now though.